# ROS Answers SE migration: Smach Tutorial

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of is there a good alternative to Smach? If not then is there a better set of tutorials than the official ROS option?

http://wiki.ros.org/smach/Tutorials

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207041/smach-tutorial/) by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2015-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To my knowledge there is no alternative to Smach. But I might be wrong.

Yep, the tutorial are good but they don't cover all that is possible with Smach. There is quite a few question around here that explain how to do more stuff with it (but I can't seem to find them again) and I have a repo on Github [where I use Smach](https://github.com/MalcolmMielle/MotherBrain) if you'd like to see but I'm not sure it's going to be really useful.

[This file expecially](https://github.com/MalcolmMielle/MotherBrain/blob/master/src/MultipleRobot/States/util.py). I know there is a good trick into this that made Smach more powerful but I used it quite a long time ago and I don't quite remember what the trick is :P.

It's pretty sad there is not more tutorial about it.

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Book **Ros By Example Volume 2** has a pretty good tutorial on Smach.  Plus it also has an alternative approach call pi_trees (behavior tree)

http://wiki.ros.org/pi_trees

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2015-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3